# While loop with flag

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, while-loop

```
public class Simulation extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean loopState = true;

    public void stopLoop() {
        loopState = false;
    }

    public void run() {     
        try {
            Robot r = new Robot();

            while (loopState) {
                r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                sleep(50);
            }
        } catch (AWTException | InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

When I launch `stopLoop()` the `while` loop below doesn't stop. If I print the value of `loopState` at the end of the `stopLoop()` call it returns `false` but the loop is still executing.

I use this code to call the methods.

```
Simulation simulation = new Simulation();
    switch (PressedButtonID) {
        case 14:
            simulation.start();
            break;
        case 15:
            simulation.stopLoop();
            break;
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite this without extending Thread as this is generally a very bad idea?  This pattern should work so I suspect you are doing something else wrong.  I would add a print statement to be sure the loop is still iterating and you haven't buffered up the key strokes.

Comment: Don't catch exceptions in empty blocks. At least an e.printStackTrace() would be helpful.

Comment: print the value of loopState in the inner while...

Comment: The value in the while is always true.

Comment: Any chance the `keyPress` method fills some sort of event buffer which stops the `Robot` from executing?  I suspect that you are blocked there and not getting around to test the `loopState` again.

Comment: No, the VK_LEFT simulation it's done correctly. I've tried removing the keyPress calls but the loop still running.

Comment: can you post the code in which you call the methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted code works perfectly, as the following simple program demonstrates: as you can see, the while loop stops as expected. The problem is somewhere else.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Simulation extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean loopState = true;

    public void stopLoop() {
        loopState = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Robot r = new Robot();

            while (loopState) {
                r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                System.out.println("Simulation loop: CALLED");
                sleep(50);
            }
        } catch (AWTException | InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Simulation simulation = new Simulation();
        simulation.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        simulation.stopLoop();
    }
}
```

Comment: First accept the answer, if it has convinced you :) Second, debug your program until you find out where it goes wrong...

Comment: Maybe you are generating events faster that they are being consumed. If so, there will be a backlog being processed even after the loop generating them has fininshed. How long does your Robot take to handle each even? More than 50 millis?